# Tableau- Display number as percentage of another field

Tags: tableau-api

I am fairly new on Tableau. Wanted help in displaying a number as percentage of another number on tableau. Excerpt of my data is below.

correct_points     points

```
 10             100
 20             130
 5              160
```

I want to display correct_points as a percentage of points. I know this can be done by creating a calculated field but was wondering if there is a faster way to represent the data as percentage. Creating calculated field will be time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Use a quick table calculation. Right click on the correct_points measure pill. Choose Quick Table Calculation. Then Percentage of Total. Depending on which way you have your data going, you may need to adjust the Computer Using option.

See https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_quick.html.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to display correct_points/points (%). This can be done with a [calculated field](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_create.htm): percentage_points = correct_points/points which you can then add as a column to your worksheet.